# Feature extraction using deep learning for more than one class

Tags: python, feature-extraction

I have a time series dataset and I want to extract its features using BRNN or CNN -RNN ( python programming language)

First, I train the model with the classification layer and obtain best accuracy.

Then, I want to take the features from one of model's hidden layer.

But I have 41 class how can I extract the features of all these classes and how I know the extracted features belong to which class?

Because I want each class with its extracted features to make some calculation later.

Comment: You can use the layer right before the classification layer, it will typically have the most significant information that is applicable to each class (the actual explanation is a little long for a comment). Whether or not a single feature belongs to a single class cannot be determined, as a feature can be associated with more than one class.

Comment: Yes , I want to extract the features from last layer before softmax layer ., but ,, how can I split the data to know the features belong to which class ..,,! Is it by using groupby ( class) to group the data by class and make the prediction for each user)! Or how ?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of it depends on what you're doing. Generally, you'll want to try an autoencoder or a transformer and do unsupervised/semisupervised learning.

Here's some material that might give some insight into some methods.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07733 (Bootstrap your own latent -- Deepmind)
https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02242 (Temporal ensembling for semisupervised learning -- Timo Aina)
https://www.coursera.org/lecture/intro-to-deep-learning/autoencoders-101-QqBOa  (Autoencoder -- Andrew Ng)

Comment: I want to use deep learning to extract time series features for 41 class